# Can I re-use an opencl image created with CL_MEM_COPY_HOST_PTR

Tags: opencl

I have created an image via

```
cl_mem preprocessIn = clCreateImage (context, CL_MEM_READ_ONLY | CL_MEM_COPY_HOST_PTR, &format, &desc,  rgbaBuffer, &error_code);
```

I would like to keep the preprocessIn image for multiple kernel runs, and just update the host memory buffer rgbaBuffer.

Is this possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CL_MEM_COPY_HOST_PTR flag only means that memory object will be initialized with values from host_ptr.

If you want to keep Host & Device memory objects in sync, you have multiple choices:

1. Read/write before/after memory update.
2. Create memory object with USE_HOST_PTR flag.
3. Create Device-side memory object first and then map it to Host side, when it's needed on Host & unmap, when it's needed on Device. In this case, no malloc/new is needed on Host side.

Comment: Thanks, Roman. For option 2, can I keep re-using the cl image, and just refresh the data on the host?

Comment: What do you mean when you say "re-using"?

Comment: I mean: do not need to destroy and re-create image object and associated memory between kernel calls.  i.e. 1) create image 2) fill host buffer 3) call kernel  4) refresh host buffer 5) call kernel again

Comment: With OpenCL 1.x in all cases you'll either need to `clEnqueueWriteImage` or `clEnqueueMapImage` & `clEnqueueUnmapMemObject` to do updates from host memory.

Comment: In that case - yes, you can keep you memory object as long as you need. Just update it.

Comment: @Dithermaster clEnqueueWriteImage enqueues a command to write from a 2D or 3D image object to host memory.  I am worrying about the other way around:  keeping the same image, and updating device memory by updating the host buffer.

Comment: @Jacko No, `clEnqueueWriteImage` is from host to device. As I said before, in OpenCL 1.x there is no way to have updates to host memory somehow just appear in the device. You must use mapping or writing.

Comment: @Dithermaster yes, you're right. But, I don't understand then what is the point of USE_HOST_PTR if you need to call clEnqueueWriteImage each time you need to update the image.

Comment: It just makes for easier first-time init. See http://streamcomputing.eu/blog/2013-02-03/opencl-basics-flags-for-the-creating-memory-objects/